# bind data to a span in button click ajax in lift framework with jquery

Tags: jquery, scala, lift

I am trying to create one simple lift web app. i want to show some data in a `<span>` in my view from the snippet JsCmds returning function. i tried the following code so far.

**In my View**

```
 <div id="ticketDiv" style="display:none;border:2px solid #FF00FF">
    <p>This is a sample div which show and hide while ajax calling</p><br />
    Ticket Number: <span id="ticketNumber"></span>
    <input id="testId" value="test"/>
 </div>
```

and **in Snippet**

```
  class ShowBookedTicket {

    def showBookedTicket(s: String): JsCmd = {      

        JsCmds.JsHideId("PGMainDiv")&
        JsCmds.JsShowId("ticketDiv")&
        JsCmds.SetValueAndFocus("testId","12345")
        //JsCmds.SetValById("ticketNumber", "1234")
        //JsCmds.SetHtml("1234","<span></span>")
         //"#ticketNumber" #> "12345" 
        //"#ticketNumber *" #> "12345"
        //JsCmds.Function("testJsFunction",List("param"),SHtml.ajaxCall( () => JsRaw("""$('#ticketDiv').show()""")).cmd)._2
         }

  def render = "*" #> {
    "#PGOK [onClick]" #> SHtml.onEvent(showBookedTicket)
  }
}
```

i tried all the commented lines too. but i didn't get any proper result. in `JsCmds.SetValueAndFocus("testId","12345")` and `JsCmds.SetValById("ticketNumber", "1234")` if i give the textbox id, then it is working. how can i fix the data in the span. can anybody give one answer.

Thanxx..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure the exact problem you are having, and am making some assumptions since you only have a part of the HTML called - for example, what is `PGMainDiv`? How is the snippet called, what is `#PGOK`, etc..

However, I assume that it looks something like:

```
  <div data-lift="ShowBookedTicket">
    <div id="ticketDiv" style="display:none;border:2px solid #FF00FF">
        <p>This is a sample div which show and hide while ajax calling</p><br />
        Ticket Number: <span id="ticketNumber"></span>
        <input id="testId" value="test"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="PGOK" />
  </div>
```

If that is the case then what you have seems to work. Therefore, I assume there are issues with the commented code. For those, there are a few items with the code:

`JsCmds.SetHtml` takes as arguments the id of the element to replace and a `NodeSeq`. The version you have commented had neither. It should work if you change it to:

```
 JsCmds.SetHtml("ticketNumber", <span>1234</span>) //No quotes around the XML
```

`"#ticketNumber" #> "12345"` won't work in your method as it is a `CssSelector` and needs to get applied to a `NodeSeq`. That would only happen inside of `render` or if you manually call `apply` on it.

Additionally, you can also issue arbitrary Javascript through `JsCmds.Run` if that makes things easier. So, you could also use jquery functions directly, like:

```
JsCmds.Run("$('#ticketNumber').html('1234')");
```

Comment: Thankyou @jcern ..`JsCmds.Run("$('#ticketNumber').html('1234')");` is working. but i don't know what is the problem with `JsCmds.SetHtml("ticketNumber", <span>1234</span>)` becuase it is showing errors like `Multiple markers at this line
 - ')' expected but integer 
  literal found.
 - not found: value <
 - ')' expected but integer 
  literal found.` in eclipse.